# Why is my jq `select` returning two values?

Tags: json, jq

In the following sample, I want a list of all the houses that have furniture.

```
[
  {
    "id": "jones house",
    "rooms": [
      {
        "name": "living room",
        "furniture": {
          "chair": "red"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "bedroom",
        "furniture": {
          "chair": "blue"
        }
      },
            {
        "name": "bathroom",
        "furniture": {
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "smith house",
    "rooms": [
      {
        "name": "basement",
        "furniture": {
          "chair": "green"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "johnson house",
    "rooms": [
      {
        "name": "study",
        "furniture": {
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am applying the following jq statement: `.[] | select(.rooms[].furniture | length > 0) | .id`, which I read as:

1. For every element in the array, send it through the pipe.
2. If the condition of the select is true, send the element that was input, unchanged, through the pipe.
3. Output the id attribute.

I am expecting:

```
"jones house"
"smith house"
```

The output looks like this, though:

```
"jones house"
"jones house"
"smith house"
```

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression) states:

> The function select(foo) produces its input unchanged if foo returns true for that input, and produces no output otherwise.

If `select` can only produce its input, unchanged, how can it be producing two "jones house" outputs?

JQPlay: https://jqplay.org/s/beaibywO2k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `rooms` has two objects complying `length > 0`, thus it's selected and printed twice. Use `any` to get your desired output:

```
.[] | select(any(.rooms[].furniture; length > 0)) | .id
```

[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uYZuRU8I57)

Comment: That works, thanks.  It seems to go against the documentation, though, which says it "produces its input unchanged."  It's producing its input twice.

Comment: @Crunch I think you misinterpreted that part. It still produces its input unchanged, but selects it twice

Comment: Yes. I think it's written in a way that is easily misunderstood.  In any case, thank you for your help.